# A shared cigarette with a friend changes a San Francisco man's DNA into physical perfection

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a story about a freelance guy in the tech industry of San Francisco who shares a cigarette with a friend of his, wakes up really sick, and transforms into physical perfection (I think his friend worked for the government).

A few random memories; while changing the man has to eat three cheeseburgers a day, wakes up really sick, and somewhere there's the phrase about his stomach being "tight as a drum." I read it about 5 years ago, possibly on Salon.com. And help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone who transforms into physical perfection? Have you been reading my diary?

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Z3HmS10N1FwJ:www.salon.com/2002/08/28/0wnz0red/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk ?

Comment: The other question does not have an accepted answer, but it does have a comment from the querent saying that it was correct.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That's good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[0wnz0red](http://www.salon.com/2002/08/28/0wnz0red/) by Cory Doctorow

> Liam fished the last cig out of the pack, crumpled it and tucked it into a pocket. “Last one,” he said. “Wanna share?”
>
> “Sure,” Murray said, dazedly. “Yeah,” he said, taking the smoke and bringing it to his lips. The tip, he realized too late, was dripping with saliva. He made a face and handed it back to Liam. “Aaagh! You juiced the filter!”

....

> “The works — I’ve viralized all the best stuff. Metabolic controllers, until further notice, you’re on a five-cheeseburger-a-day diet; increased dendrite density; muscle-builders. At-will pain-dampeners. You’ll need those — I gave you the interface, too.”
>
> A spasm shot up Murray’s back, then down again.
>
> “It was on the cigarette butt. You’re cancer-immune, by the by. I’m extra contagious tonight.” Liam turned down his collar to show Murray the taped lump there, the dangling cable that disappeared down his shirt, connecting to the palmtop strapped to his belt.

And, the "stomach tight as a drum" line:

> But his gut was gone, tight as a drumhead.

Comment: [Seems likely](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138653/sf-short-story-identification-a-shared-cigarette-with-a-friend-changes-a-san-fr#comment351117_138653)

Comment: ^_^ Did you just comment with a link to the post you're commenting on?

Comment: I do that [sometimes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138653/a-shared-cigarette-with-a-friend-changes-a-san-francisco-mans-dna-into-physical/138654?noredirect=1#comment351120_138654).